# Incompatible Java versions. Eclipse running under 0

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I wanted to create a JFrame (got all the Swing libraries needed) but this is what shows up on the design tab. I've been looking for similar problems but it only shows some other specific numbers , for example "Eclipse is running under 1.6" or "1.7" etc. But never have I seen "Eclipse running under 0" , what does this even mean? I uninstalled java and eclipse and re-installed them all over again...same problem. The execution works fine but I want to be able to edit the look of the frame on the design tab too.

[image]

Comment: Is that a giant hyperlink?

Comment: My mistake, I just edited it.

Comment: Include the screenshot, not a link to it.

Comment: I don't think they're allowing screenshots to be presented directly. You either click on the link or edit it since I don't know how, then I'll approve your edition.

Comment: Did you really just downvote my question because of this?
If yes...Do you (or if not, whoever downvoted it) realize that there are only 2 people on the entire internet that made this question, the first one never got an answer from an old rusty forum, I'm the second one and I'm getting a downvote because someone is just lazy to click on a link...wow. Some people in this community really do suck.

Comment: I edited your post, and no, I didn’t downvote. However, at a guess it was because originally it was a giant link, then just a link. You can read on the help page why this is frowned upon (links may be broken, may lead to malicious software etc). That’s just a guess though. Of course it’s an anonymous voting system, so someone could have downvoted for absolutely no reason either.

Comment: Are you using jdk9 or 10? Perhaps try with 7 or 8.

Comment: See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50228100/2849346,  it's a known bug with Java version strings in Window Builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled JDK 10 and got the JDK 8u171 instead. And it's working just like it should have. You're just gonna have to change all of your project's JRE System Library to [jre1.8.0_171] and the compiler too and you're good to go.
So far I only tried version 8 and it works, haven't tried other versions but my own thought is that the problem is with version 10, which means maybe version 9 works too but I  didn't want to give it a go. (is there even a version 9 of JDK? I don't see any...)

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to Window->Preferences->Java->Compilerand check your compliance level. Make sure it is set to 10.

Comment: It is at 10, still doesn't work.

Comment: In your package explorer, what does it say you are using? It should look something like "JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]"

Comment: Not exactly, it's  "JRE System Library [JavaSE-10]"

Comment: That's what you should have. Perhaps WindowBuilder does not work with Java 10 yet as it is fairly new. Try altering your Eclipse and project to use an older version of Java

Comment: Created a new project* with JavaSE-1.6, still the same problem...

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50228100/2849346 - it's a known bug with Java version strings in Window Builder.