# Eclipse Oxygen : Incompatible java versions

Tags: java, eclipse, version, eclipse-oxygen

I have just installed Eclipse Oxygen and created a JFrame project. While switching from source view to design view, i am getting "incompatible java version error".

Full error Desc : Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.

I checked version in windows --> preferences --> java --> compiler where compiler compliance level is 10
and checked in Project Properties --> java compiler --> compiler compliance level is 10.

How to resolve this problem? i surfed google but nothing works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windowbuilder currently does not work with Java 9 or 10. This is described in Eclipse bug [517291](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=517291).

Running Eclipse with Java 8 seems to be the only way to run windowbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I just asked the same question on 5th of May and I found the answer myself.
Yet MY QUESTION is marked as "duplicate" whereas you were the one to ask the same exact question 3 days after me.
Yall must be so desperate to get points. -_-
[Incompatible Java versions. Eclipse running under 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50193407/incompatible-java-versions-eclipse-running-under-0)