# Eclipse Windowbuilder Incompatible Java

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I already tried the solutions posted in stackoverflow.com like :

[Eclipse Oxygen : Incompatible java versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50227902/eclipse-oxygen-incompatible-java-versions/50400175#50400175)

it does not solve my problem, I still have the following message in attachment :

[image]

I have Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a) on Mac and the latest version of Windowbuilder.

Comment: The first link points to your screenshot. Do you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50263816/6505250)? What did you try?

Comment: Ah sorry, I just rectified it.

Comment: edit **eclipse.ini** file located at root of eclipse folder and update the java version there .Make sure u have java installed on your system properly for version 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit **eclipse.ini** file located at root of eclipse folder and update the java version there .Make sure u have java installed on your system properly for version 1.8

Comment: Right-click it (or control click) and select "Show Package Contents".  Eclipse application is actually a directory. You should find eclipse.ini at **Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini** inside the Eclipse application directory.

Also make sure you set your java_home to something like:
**JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)**

Comment: Thx @SahilGupta, I resolved the problem with adding -vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin in my eclipse.ini file